# Do Schengen entry points now use automated kiosks on non-EU travellers as of 2023-2024?

Tags: schengen

Are non-EU travellers entering the Schengen area still having to get manual passport stamps at entry point as of 2023?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, some EU countries are using automated kiosks for certain non-EU travellers.

At the same time, it is still yes to manual passport stamps. Until the electronic [Entry/Exit System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry/Exit_System) is finally put into place in <s>2020</s> <s>2022</s> <s>May 2023</s> <s>by the end of 2023</s> <s>early 2024</s> October 2024?, most third-country nationals travelling to the Schengen area for short visits still need to obtain entry and exit stamps, which are the only Schengen-wide prima facie (that is, presumed to be conclusive) evidence so far of respecting (or not) the period of stay allowed.

Several countries, e.g. France and the Netherlands, have now allowed certain third-country nationals to use automated passport kiosks to enter and/or exit Schengen area. However, generally, these travellers will still need to see an immigration officer (usually very briefly without questions, but they can still question you) to obtain a stamp after passing the electronic gates.

Germany has also started to allow holders of German residence permits to use automated kiosk in certain cases, since they are generally exempt from verification of allowed period of stay.

Comment: My wife (UK) and I (Irish) passed through Amsterdam Schiphol last week.  On the way in, the automated gates were EU only.  On the way out, several other nationalities, including the UK, could use the automated gates.  My wife got a message to go to a desk where an officer quickly stamped her passport.  I didn't get this message.  I forget the full list of countries but I don't think it said all.  There were pictures of flags.

Comment: @badjohn You didn't get the message because you are not to be stamped as a EU citizen

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Yes, of course.  The officer knew who to expect.  I guess that there is an indicator on the other side of the gate.  I have used these gates many times before but it is the first time that my wife has.

Comment: @badjohn The [list](https://english.marechaussee.nl/topics/self-service-passport-control) includes all EU / EEA countries, Switzerland, US, UK, Japan, South Korea…

Comment: @Relaxed That fits my  memory: the obvious EU / EEA / CH and also UK and a few others.  In contrast, the UK allows the eGates both in and out for a rather longer list of countries.

Answer (score 5):

It was the case in Frankfurt last Monday and Wednesday. The gates were marked "All passports" and there were manned counters for non-EU citizens to get a stamp. A stark change from 4 years ago when the electronic gates were EU citizens only.

Comment: And from three years ago, when automatic gates were closed to everyone, at least in the few airports I saw during the height of the COVID lockdown.

Comment: I didn't see any airport between March 2020 and April 2023... I wouldn't know... :-)

Comment: @phoog Or almost every single time I’ve flown in and out of CPH, where the automatic gates that they spent ages installing are consistently closed to everyone all the time for no discernible reason…

Comment: Considering how frequently 3-, 5-, 10-year-old questions pop up, "last Monday and Wednesday" isn't all that useful. You might consider an edit to include the actual calendar dates.'